# biblatex: change name of author according to language?

Tags: biblatex, languages, babel

Usually a name stays the same in whatever language. So, whenever I quote a work by Knuth -- be it in an English article or a German one -- I will quote him as `Donald E. Knuth`.

This is not always the case with ancient or medieval names. They are spelled differently in different languages. Two examples in English | German | French:

- Aristotle | Aristoteles | Aristote
- Thomas Aquinas | Thomas von Aquin | Thomas d'Aquin

This means that when I write an English article, I need a `bib`-file that contains the English names, but when I want to write a German article, I need to go through my bib file and change the names accordingly. Depending on how often I in fact publish in English or German this could keep me busy and is prone to error.

So, I though, maybe I could have the different names already included in one single `bib`-file and let `biblatex` choose the correct name according to the primary language used in the document. Any ideas?

NB: I do not want to use in one single document both spellings Aristotle and Aristoteles (as the following MWE might make you think). Of course, if the article's primary language is English, then all the references to Aristotle will use the English spelling of his name. However, I want to be able to write articles in different languages, without (a) having to edit my `bib`-files each time or (b) generally maintaing not one single `bib`-file but two different ones, one for each language, or (c) having two distinct entries in one `bib`-file

### MWE

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}    
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[ngerman, british]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose,abbreviate=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{aristotle:ross:1924,
    Author = {Aristotle},    % It is here, I think, that something could be done, e.g., ...
    Title = {Metaphysics},     % ... british=Aristotle,ngerman=Aristoteles,french=Aristote
    Editor = {William David Ross},
    Commentator = {William David Ross},
    Introduction = {William David Ross},
    Hyphenation = {british},
    Location = {Oxford},
    Publisher = {Clarendon Press},
    Volumes = {2},
    Year = {1924}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{british}
Some English text.\footcite{aristotle:ross:1924}

\selectlanguage{ngerman}
Etwas Text auf Deutsch.\footcite{aristotle:ross:1924}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{aristotle:ross:1924,
    Author = {\Aristotle},    % It is here, I think, that something could be done, e.g., ...
    Title = {Metaphysics},     % ... british=Aristotle,ngerman=Aristoteles,french=Aristote
    Editor = {William David Ross},
    Commentator = {William David Ross},
    Introduction = {William David Ross},
    Hyphenation = {british},
    Location = {Oxford},
    Publisher = {Clarendon Press},
    Volumes = {2},
    Year = {1924}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}    
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[ngerman,french,british]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose,abbreviate=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newauthor}{mm}
 {
  \clint_newauthor:nn {#1} {#2}
 }
\tl_new:N \l__clint_author_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \clint_newauthor:nn #1 #2
 {
  \prop_new:c { g_clint_author_#1_prop }
  \tl_set:Nn \l__clint_author_tl { #1 }
  \keys_set:nn { clint-author } { #2 }
  \cs_new:cpn { #1 } { \prop_get:cV { g_clint_author_#1_prop } \languagename }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_get:Nn { cV }
\keys_define:nn { clint-author }
 {
  unknown .code:n = 
   \prop_gput:cVn { g_clint_author_ \l__clint_author_tl _prop }
                  \l_keys_key_tl
                  { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newauthor{Aristotle}{
 british=Aristotle,
 ngerman=Aristoteles,
 french=Aristote
}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{british}
Some English text.\footcite{aristotle:ross:1924}

\selectlanguage{ngerman}
Etwas Text auf Deutsch.\footcite{aristotle:ross:1924}

\selectlanguage{french}
Du texte en Français.\footcite{aristotle:ross:1924}

\end{document}
```

You define a control sequence with

```
\newauthor{Aristotle}{
 british=Aristotle,
 ngerman=Aristoteles,
 french=Aristote
}
```

The command will be called `\Aristotle` (but the string is arbitrary). The command should be used in the `.bib` file. Maybe it's possible to use `biblatex` methods for processing the author name without changing it.

[image]

Comment: Note that as of September 2014, `\prop_get:Nn` has been renamed to `\prop_item:Nn`

Answer (score 7):

This isn't really an "answer" per se. However. This is planned for biblatex 4.0/biber 4.0. You will (hopefully) be able to define alternatives like this:

```
AUTHOR = {Aristotle},
AUTHOR_translated_ngerman = {Aristoteles},
AUTHOR_translated_french = {Aristote}
```

and then pick these out within the style as:

```
\printname{author}
\printname[form=translated,lang=ngerman]{author}
\printname[form=translated,lang=french]{author}
```

probably switched using `\selectlanguage` as @egreg shows.

This sort of (optional, for backwards compatibility) form/lang interface is planned for any macros dealing with fields, list or names. Work is underway, the biber part is already done, the biblatex part is underway but is quite some work.

Comment: Are there any news about `biblatex 3.0/biber 2.0`? Or is there a release date already on the horizon?

Comment: It will be 4.0/4.0 and these are already available in the EXPERIMENTAL folders on SF.

Comment: how do I install these on Mac OS X? Is there a brief guide somewhere on the net?

Comment: It's just a manual install in your local texmf tree - I suspect that there are several examples of this on TSE. However, I wouldn't recommend it at the moment - I have to refactor some of the 4.0 things in the light of recent testing and the interfaces are likely to change.

Comment: Dear @PLK, Are there any news about the mentioned feature: "AUTHOR_translated_ngerman"?
My main question is that the following format is planned yet or cancelled?
FIELDNAME_translated_LANG

Comment: Greetings, yes, there is a new "multiscript" branch which implements this. It is currently experimental but has updated documentation. You will need to manually get biblatex and biber 4.0 from here to try it. It *should* be backwards compatible ...

https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/experimental/ and https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/files/experimental/