# Localize fields in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, babel

I'm trying to write a document using a `.bib` as a database of entries, and then formatting them. However, I need to have some entries in multiple languages.

So, is there an easy way to localize fields in a `.bib` entry, such that I can extend the model.

For example, now I'm using a really straightforward way to change between languages of each entry

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{localized}

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
  description-english,
  description-spanish,
}

\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[localized]{
  description-english,
  description-spanish,
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@localized{entry1,
  description-english = {this is english},
  description-spanish = {esto es español}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[datamodel=\jobname]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{description-spanish}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{description-english}{#1}
\newbibmacro*{langfield}[1]{%
  \expandafter\iffieldundef\expandafter{#1-\languagename}{}{\expandafter\printfield\expandafter{#1-\languagename}}%
}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{localized}{%
  \usebibmacro{langfield}{description}
}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}
\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

However, this becomes really hard to manage if I have several entries that should be in multiple languages, as I need to declare each in the data model. Also, it does not support some spelling changes. For example, if I want to put a university field, in Spanish it is spelled "Universidad X" while in English it should be "X University", or in some cases "University X".

Thus, having a way to default some fields or macros would be useful. Is there something that I can use to achieve such behavior from `biblatex`?

Comment: Something like this is planned for future releases; see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107874/8528), especially the "answer" by @PLK.  If you want to experiment, you can try the experimental biblatex 4.0 branch at its [Sourceforge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/files/experimental/).